# HttpMessageNotReadable Exceotion: JSON parse error: cannot deserialize instance of ArrayList out of start object token

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson, spring-rest

I have an endpoint

```
@GetMapping(value = "/accounts/{accountId}/placementInfo", headers = "version=1")
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
  public List<PlacementDetail> findPlacementDetailByPlacementInfoAtTime(@PathVariable("accountId") Long accountId,
                                                                        @RequestParam(value = "searchDate", required = false)
                                                                        @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) LocalDate searchDate) {}
```

And I am sending the request by using rest template

```
placementResponseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(placementUriBuilder(accountId, searchDate), HttpMethod.GET,
          apiRequestEntity,new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<PlacementDetail>>() {});
```

with a helper method

```
 private String placementUriBuilder(long accountId, LocalDate searchDate) throws IOException {
        String resourceUri = ACCOUNT_RESOURCE_URI_START + accountId + PLACEMENT_DETAIL_RESOURCE_URI_END;
        String url;

        if(searchDate != null) {
          url = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUri(serverUri.getUri()).path(resourceUri).queryParam("searchDate", searchDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE)).build().toUriString();
        } else {
          url = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUri(serverUri.getUri()).path(resourceUri).build().toUriString();
        }
        return url;
      }
```

When I look at the SO people talk about sending the object and failing as the created JSON is in wrong format but here this is a get api and I do not understand the source of the problem.

Comment: It's expecting an array of `PlacementDetail` to be returned by the `GET`, it's receiving an object (i.e. json starting with `{`).

Comment: Check the returned json with curl or similar.

Comment: It works fine when the api returns list of one object! Is it expected behaviour? how? trying to understand

Comment: When the api returns List<PlacementDetail> how it will get array? sorry this was written by someone and I am trying to understand

Comment: Container types like `List` are typically serialized as json arrays. The deserialiser is expecting a json array, which it will create a `List` from.

Comment: I'm just guessing, but the json that is causing the problem is probably an error object. Check the returned json.

Comment: Any solution to fix the problem?. Endpoint returns list so it shouldn't create problem if it deserilize as json array

Comment: The api is returning proper json when request is made from postman. When i tested it , request is not reached endpoint and failed at the client side

Answer (score 1):

This is commonly caused by a missing error handler on your `RestTemplate`. Your server responds with an error and your client tries to deserialize it to a `List<PlacementDetail>`. In order to address this, you should properly handle HTTP error codes.

See the below snippet.

```
@Configuration
public class ClientConfig {

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
        return restTemplateBuilder
                .errorHandler(new ClientErrorHandler())
                .build();
    }


    public class ClientErrorHandler implements ResponseErrorHandler {

        @Override
        public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse httpResponse) throws IOException {
            // check if HTTP status signals an error response
            return !HttpStatus.OK.equals(httpResponse.getStatusCode());
        }

        @Override
        public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse httpResponse) throws IOException {
            // handle exception case as you see fit
            throw new RuntimeException("Error while making request");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: The api is giving proper response when request is made from postman! Also it is not causing the issue when the response contains one object in the list

Comment: Are you testing the exact same request from postman (i.e. the postman request is done with `searchDate` and the request you do from code is done with `searchDate` as well)?